# Kill the [live] tag

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-cleanup-request

[live](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/live) is undefined and used in many ways:

- booting into memory-resident OS
- streaming multi-media
- accomplishing a secondary task during an active process
- Windows Live
- etc., including irrelevant usage

Virtually all of the uses have existing specific tags.  Recommend deleting [live] and replacing the questions' tags with the relevant specific ones.

Comment: No more lives remaining.

Answer (score 1):

And this is [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)....